# Storing multiple values from item selected - Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to retrieve data from my JS view into my controller and save to my database. For my `item_id` i am able to retrieve every selected item's id.

But when i enter quantity for items selected, in my database, the quantity that appears for all items selected is the first quantity entered.

So if i have,

```
Item: HpBook

Qty : 5

Item: Mac

Qty: 10
```

In the database, the quantity for mac is also saved as 5. What am i doing wrong?

**JS**

```
$('.form').append(
        '<div class="container"> '+
        '<input type="hidden"  value='+item.id+' data-id="'+item.id+'"   name="item_id[]" />'+  
        '<input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder=" Enter Value " name="quantity" />'+
        '<p class="total" >Figures  $:<span name="figures" id="figures"></span></p>'+
         '</div>'

);
```

**Controller**

```
 $item = new Item(array(
             'total' => $request->get('figures'),                    
         ));

 $item->save();
 $item->products()->attach($request->get('item_id'),['quantity' => $request->get('quantity')]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, fix the typo for quantity name:

```
'<input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder=" Enter Value " name="quantity[]" />'+
```

In your controller, first make an array for products, then attach it to the model:

```
$products = [];
foreach($request->get('item_id') as $key => $id) {
    $products[$id] = ['quantity' => $request->get('quantity')[$key]];
}
$item->products()->attach($products);
```

Comment: I have added array_combine, just exactly how you have presented your answer

Answer (score 0):

your js have missing `[]`

should be:

```
$('.form').append(
    '<div class="container"> '+
    '<input type="hidden"  value='+item.id+' data-id="'+item.id+'"   name="item_id[]" />'+  
    '<input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder=" Enter Value " name="quantity[]" />'+
    '<p class="total" >Figures  $:<span name="figures" id="figures"></span></p>'+
     '</div>'

);
```

Comment: well yes, this happends because of this `$item->products()->attach($request->get('item_id'),['quantity' => $request->get('quantity')]);`, request()->quantity is array now, so you have to iterate it

Comment: But then how do i iterate that?